# Why do the CSS property border-collapse and empty-cells conflict?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can use the CSS property `border-collapse` to combine the borders of adjacent table cells. And I can use `empty-cells` to hide table cells that have no content. But when I use both, the `empty-cells` property has no effect and empty cells are always visible. At least there's a border around each of them, even where multiple adjacent rows and columns are empty.

Here's an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th,
td
{
    empty-cells: hide;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer your question title, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#empty-cells) does not define the behavior of `empty-cells` in the collapsing border model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [**@Bolt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758373/why-do-the-css-attributes-border-collapse-and-empty-cells-conflict/18758436#comment27651648_18758373) explained why this happens, I will provide a solution for this, you can use the below snippet in your CSS to hide the empty cells

```
th:empty, td:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NX5Q/)

Using `:empty` pseudo, I set the `border: 0;` so physically the element is present on the page, we just target the styles of the empty cells and set the `borders` to `0`.

I didn't used `display: none;` as it will spoil your `table` layout, so using the above snippet is enough if you want to keep the border collapsed.

Note: The selector am using is a general selector and will target globally, if you want to target the element specifically, consider using a `class` instead like

```
.table_class_name th:empty, 
.table_class_name td:empty { 
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. The `:empty` selector works just as I wanted it. Fortunately, it's available from IE9 on which is the minimum requirement for my project. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: @LonelyPixel you welcome, even if you want to have support for older versions, you can check this out - http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is a trick that I found, you can use border-collapse as separate. then you define border-spacing to 0px into your table then define the padding in your td to 0px.

```css
table
{ 
 empty-cells: hide; 
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0px; 
}

td
{ 
 border: thin solid black;
 text-align: right; 
 padding: 0px;
}

th 
{ 
 border: thin solid black;
 background-color: yellow; 
}
```