# border-collapse and empty-cells doesn't work properly together

Tags: html, css

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Tables

> You can hide them by specifying empty-cells: hide;. Then, if a cell's
>   parent element has a background, it shows through the empty cell.

It works well but when set `border-collapse: collapse;` it doesn't.
I found [Why do the CSS property border-collapse and empty-cells conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758373/why-do-the-css-attributes-border-collapse-and-empty-cells-conflict) but the answer just hide border of empty cells and it doesn't show a background of a parent element.

In this sample if we add border-collapse to `table#ok` background of parent element will hide itself but it shouldn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/37m56vwb/1/

How to explain this behavior and how to fix it if possible?

**UPD**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="ok">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and css:

```
table {
    background: green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table#ok { border-collapse: separate; }

th,td {
    background: blue;
    empty-cells: hide;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

th:empty, td:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include your relevant code in the question itself. Jsfiddle is a useful addition, not a substitute for including the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
background:transparent;
```

to

```
th:empty, td:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

The reason the hidden cells don't show through is mentioned in the W3.org spec. Border-collapse ignores the fact that the th or td was hidden. Basically, by you collapsing the borders, you are causing the empty-cells:hide to be ignored -- and therefore the normal background of the th and td are being shown.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-empty-cells

When using border-collapse, W3 Schools says: borders are collapsed into a single border when possible (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp Or read the spec from W3.org here: http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#img-tbl-empty

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. The half of the question has been solved.

Comment: @edem When using border-collapse, W3 Schools says:
borders are collapsed into a single border when possible (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Or read the spec from W3.org here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#img-tbl-empty

Comment: Excellent. @Jon, add it to the answer, I'll accept it.